# Sql Server Reporting Services parameter passing

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bids

I am creating a report such that when you click on a data point it opens up another report providing the details of that datapoint. My problem is the parameter passing. What I want to pass is the information from that datapoint.

Thanks!

Comment: In the subreport that I am trying to open. I have a query that has the where clause: where prop_id = @ PropID So I want @PropID to be the parameter sent from the main report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the cell the you use to navigate to the sub-report and choose Properties. Click the Navigation tab. In the Hyperlink action section where it says Jump to Report click the Parameters button. This shows the parameters of the linked report and allows you to put expressions of what values you want to pass, such as field values, etc. To pass your parameter value, put in:

```
=Parameters!PropID.Value
```